# Is there a mitzvah to kill an apikorus that did teshuva?

Tags: halacha, heresy, cherem

In Yoreh De’ah 158:2 it says that there is a mitzvah to kill an apikorus. Assuming this is in the time of the Temple (i.e Jewish/religious autonomy), if that person did teshuva, is there still a mitzvah to kill him? What if his teshuva wasn’t publicized?

Answer (score 3):

The Rambam writes in Perush Ha-Mishnah (Chullin ch. 1) that the purpose of executing an apikores is to remove the espousal of his ideas from society; thus if the apikores did teshuvah he would certainly no longer be executed:

> ודע כי מסורת בידינו מאבותינו כפי שקבלוהו קבוצה מפי קבוצה כי זמנינו זה
>   זמן הגלות שאין בו דיני נפשות אינו אלא בישראל שעבר עברת מיתה, אבל
>   המינים והצדוקים והביתוסים לכל שינוי שיטותיהם הרי כל מי שהתחיל אותה
>   השטה תחלה ייהרג לכתחלה **כדי שלא יטעה את ישראל ויקלקל את האמונה**, וכבר
>   נעשה מזה הלכה למעשה באנשים רבים בכל ארץ המערב

Answer (score 1):

Rambam in Hilchot Teshuva 1:3 writes:

> התשובה מכפרת על כל העבירות אפילו רשע כל ימיו ועשה תשובה באחרונה אין מזכירין לו שום דבר מרשעו שנאמר רשעת הרשע לא יכשל בה ביום שובו מרשעו
>
> Teshuvah atones for all sins. Even a person who was wicked his whole life and repented in his final moments will not be reminded of any aspect of his wickedness as [Ezekiel 33:12] states "the wickedness of the evil one will not cause him to stumble on the day he repents his wickedness."
>
> ([Touger translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911888/jewish/Teshuvah-Chapter-One.htm))

In Hilchot teshuva 3:14 he expands this to include even heretics:

> במה דברים אמורים שכל אחד מאלו אין לו חלק לעוה"ב כשמת בלא תשובה אבל אם שב מרשעו ומת והוא בעל תשובה הרי זה מבני העולם הבא שאין לך דבר שעומד בפני התשובה אפילו כפר בעיקר כל ימיו ובאחרונה שב יש לו חלק לעולם הבא שנאמר שלום שלום לרחוק ולקרוב אמר ה' ורפאתיו כל הרשעים והמומרים וכיוצא בהן שחזרו בתשובה בין בגלוי בין במטמוניות מקבלין אותן שנאמר שובו בנים שובבים אע"פ שעדין שובב הוא שהרי בסתר שב ולא בגלוי מקבלין אותו בתשובה
>
> However, if such a person repents from his wicked deeds and dies as a Baal-Teshuvah, he will merit the world to come, for nothing can stand in the way of Teshuvah.
>
> Even if he denies God's existence throughout his life and repents in his final moments, he merits a portion in the world to come as implied by [Isaiah 57:19] "'Peace, peace, to the distant and the near,' declares God. 'I will heal him.'"
>
> Any wicked person, apostate, or the like, who repents, whether in an open, revealed manner or in private, will be accepted as implied by [Jeremiah 3:22] "Return, faithless children." [We may infer] that even if one is still faithless, as obvious from the fact that he repents in private and not in public, his Teshuvah will be accepted.
>
> ([Touger translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/911896/jewish/Teshuvah-Chapter-Three.htm))

Comment: this doesn’t answer whether or not he’d be liable for death if day his teshuva wasn’t public